# g.726 ADPCM codec stopped working in VLC

Tags: 12.04, vlc

After upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 vlc can't work with codec g.726.

```
[0x7fbdc80009c8] avcodec generic error: cannot open codec (G.726 ADPCM Audio)
```

But avplay works fine with this codec.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Exact same thing happened to me after an update/upgrade: Avplay worked fine but vlc was jerky and distorted.

Not sure if it is relevant but my Ubuntu is 12.04 EXTIX x64 is running in a VirtualBox guest.

I found a workaround within, VLC by changing Tools -> Preferences -> Video -> output from "Default" to "X11 Video Output(XCB)". This corrected the problem for me.

Hope this helps.

Good Journeys, Brad